# How to validate existence and values of some object properties based on the value of a Type object property?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate JSON which is more complex than what's below, but hopefully this simpler example illustrates the issue cleanly.

Within the more complex schema, I need to have an array of objects, where:

- All objects have a set of the same properties, like **Name** and **Type**
- The **Type** property is an enum of allowed object types, such as "Full-Time", "Contractor"
- Based on the value of the **Type** property, an additional per-type set of properties is defined. For example a "Full-Time" Employee has a **Salary** property which is required and an **Email** property which is optional, while a "Contractor" Employee has a **Rate** property which is required, and no optional additional properties.
- Only properties which are defined should be allowed within each object
- Required properties for each object may include those which are common across all objects, such as **Name** and **Type**, as well as those specific to one type of object, such as **Salary**

This seems like it should be a common problem, but so far I have not been able to find something which seems to match exactly what I'm trying to do. These came close, but I could not figure out exactly how to apply them to and/or which method is best for my use-case, so hoping someone who understands this area better can help:

- [Is it possible to have common properties before oneOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834982/is-it-possible-to-have-common-properties-before-oneof)
- [How to validate a JSON object against a JSON schema based on object's type described by a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823500/how-to-validate-a-json-object-against-a-json-schema-based-on-objects-type-descr)
- [how to set the type of a schema object based on the value of another property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881623/how-to-set-the-type-of-a-schema-object-based-on-the-value-of-another-property)
- [JsonSchema: Validate type based on value of another property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784760/jsonschema-validate-type-based-on-value-of-another-property)

In particular, it's not clear how the required and additionalProperties keywords should work across the common vs per-object properties.

Schema I have so far, with unwanted duplication:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Employee"
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Employee": {
      "type": "object",
      "oneOf": [{
        "properties": {
          "Name": { "type": "string" },
          "Type": { "type": "string", "enum": [ "Full-Time" ] },
          "Salary": { "type": "integer" },
          "Email": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": [ "Name", "Type", "Salary" ],
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "Name": { "type": "string" },
          "Type": { "type": "string", "enum": [ "Contractor" ] },
          "Rate": { "type": "number" }
        },
        "required": [ "Name", "Type", "Rate" ],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

To validate this data:

```
[
  { "Name": "Good First Employee",    "Type": "Full-Time",  "Salary": 100000, "Email": "first.employee@example.com"  },
  { "Name": "Good Second Employee",   "Type": "Full-Time",  "Salary":  90000 },
  { "Name": "Good First Contractor",  "Type": "Contractor", "Rate": 20.00 },
  { "Name": "Good Second Contractor", "Type": "Contractor", "Rate": 25 },
  { "Name": "Bad First Person",       "Type": "Unknown",    "Salary":  90000 },
  { "Name": "Bad Third Employee",     "Type": "Full-Time" },
  { "Name": "Bad Fourth Employee",    "Type": "Full-Time",  "Rate": 49.00 },
  { "Name": "Bad Fifth Employee",     "Type": "Full-Time",  "Salary": 100000, "Phone": "123-123-1234" },
  { "Name": "Bad Second Person" }
]
```

For the data above, objects with a **Name** starting with "Good" are valid. The rest starting with "Bad" are invalid:

- Bad First Person - invalid Type
- Bad Third Employee - missing Salary
- Bad Fourth Employee - missing Salary, Rate invalid for Employee
- Bad Fifth Employee - Phone invalid for Employee
- Bad Second Person - missing Type (a common field)

Some of this works, but with excessive error messages that don't clearly indicate where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It IS a common problem. Sadly your unwanted duplication is the only way to make what you want happen for a draft-7 JSON Schema.

We (JSON Schema core team) did a lot of work on adding a new keyword for draft-8, but that's not published / done yet. https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/556 - `unevaluatedProperties`.

The linked issue includes a lot of detail, including an example of where the OpenAPI specification has the same issue, and uses lots of deuplication as a result. The new key word cuts out lots of duplication.